# Elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods

This method returns the maximum absolute difference between elements in one `array`. It calculates the difference between all numbers in the `array` but I'm trying to adapt it to returns the **index** of the maximum absolute difference.

For example:

```
Array = [7, 19, 5, 10, 16, 8, 1, 19, 6, 13] 
Index = [0, 01, 2, 03, 04, 5, 6, 07, 8, 09]
```

In this array, the biggest absolute difference is `18` (= 1-19) and it happens in index number `6`.

Also, if there are multiple equal differences the method needs to return the one of higher index. In the example above it would return index `3` instead of `0`

```
    Array = [1, 19, 5, 1, 19]
    Index = [0, 01, 2, 3, 04]
```

This problem is a little bit complicate and I'm not figuring out how to do it. Does any one know?

```
public static int stepMaxDiff(int[] array){

        int diff = 0;
        int max = 0;

        if (array.length == 0){    // Checks for empty array and returns -1
            return -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i){ // i is the element in the array

            if (i == array.length - 1){
                diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[0]); 
                // Calculates the last element of the array minus the first one

            } else {
                diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i+1]);
                // Calculates the element i minus element [i+1]
            }   

            max = diff >= max ? diff : max;
        }

        return max;
    }
```

Comment: Is this an assignement? I'm sure you're able to do it. Just take a pen and a paper and try by doing it step by step. Ask yourself the right questions. This is plain logic, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `maxIndex` to `max`, and store it every time you update the `max`:

```
if (diff >= max) {
    max = diff;
    maxIndex = i;
}
```

You could avoid storing `max` altogether, replacing it by `maxIndex`, but then you would need to re-calculate the `max` on each iteration, which may be sub-optimal.

Comment: Thank you! This `if` statement works but not for all cases. For example, array [4,18] needs to return 1 (because is 18 - 4) but it returns 0.

Comment: @Rods2292 That's because your loop "wraps around" incorrectly. You should make the condition either `i <= array.length - 1` or `i < array.length`, whichever you like more, because the wrap around logic is there anyway.

Comment: That's true! I didn't notice that `i <= array.length - 1` was written without `=` symbol.